# .net core microservices deployed on Windows 2012 R2 freezes after days working fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microservices

I have two different microservices developed in C#. They listen in a Port for a GET call and returns a JSON. They have been developed by two different persons and run in two different servers (Windows 2012 R2)

They work well for days, but at a certain moment stop returning the JSON after making the call

If I access the server via RDP I can see that the microservice console is frozen, when it should be showing the log. If I press a key, the microservice works again for a while that could be days. But the problem appears again sooner or later (sometimes in minutes).

Restarting the microservice did not fix the problem.

I tried to use netstat to see if there were any problems like a lot of open sockets, but not.

The program starts this way in program.cs

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().Build())
             .UseKestrel((ctx, opt) =>
             {
                 opt.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8098);
                 opt.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("5.35.249.161"), 8098);
             })
             .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

And the action returns an

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
```

I consulted the sysadmin but he could not find anything out from normal.

We cannot understand why the microservices (programmed by two different persons in two different countries and no copy/paste one from another and running on different servers) behave that way.

Comment: Have you tried deploying them in a different server? That might rule in or out the environment Vs the code

Comment: You say that pressing a key in the console makes it run again. Did you know that on windows, if you click with the mouse in a console app it will freeze the app? As a hint to know if someone blocked the console this way, there is a white rectangle somewhere visible (like a frozen entry cursor)

Comment: In that regard, it's not a great idea to have a production app just running in a console window exposed to the desktop. *Anything* can happen, especially if users can log into the machine. If this is how you want to run, it would be better to deploy as a service. That way, there's no open window that can be tampered with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bruno Belmondo comment points me to the solution.

The problem is that I or other programmers of the team clicked with the mouse in the console app and therefore the microservice frozen.

The long term solution (as we have around 10 microservices and will have more in the future) is to use Chris Pratt solution and convert the microservices into windows services.